# Issue with performing add/update to CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, addition

I've an `NSArray` holds a few `NSDictionary`, each and every time I save an `NSDictionary` object and add it to the `NSArray`, I send it to add/update function.
I know I read the data correct, and when I used to add the data with no update function, all data inserted to the `CoreData`, but I want to add the update function to verify the data I put.
Right now, the function add the first object, then over and over again go to 'update'.
Whats wrong?

My code:

```
-(void)updateOrAddTrap:(NSMutableDictionary*)trapObject
{
    NSInteger trapID = [trapObject[@"id"] integerValue];
    Trap *trapEntity = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    Boolean success = true;

    self.fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Trap"];
    self.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trapID == %d", trapID];
    [self.fetchRequest setPredicate:self.predicate];

    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (results == nil)
    {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"HANDLE ERROR");
        success = false;
    }
    else if ([results count] == 0)
    {
        // Nothing to update, add new trap
        NSLog(@"NOTHING TO UPDATE | ADD NEW");

        // Create a new record (row)
        trapEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trap" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"UPDATE EXISTING OBJECT");
        trapEntity = results[0]; // There should be only one object for the ID.
    }


    if (trapEntity != nil)
    {
        // Set properties for new or existing object ...

        // Int
        int alarmDistance = [[trapObject objectForKey:ALARMDISTANCE] intValue];
        int type = [[trapObject objectForKey:TYPE] intValue];
        int roadNumber = [[trapObject objectForKey:ROADNUMBER] intValue];
        int trap_id = [[trapObject objectForKey:ID] intValue];
        int polys = [[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGONS] intValue];
        int degrees = [[trapObject objectForKey:DEGREES] intValue];
        [trapEntity setAlarmDistance:[NSNumber numberWithInt:alarmDistance]];
        [trapEntity setType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:type]];
        [trapEntity setRoadNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:roadNumber]];
        [trapEntity setTrapID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trap_id]];
        [trapEntity setPolys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:polys]];
        [trapEntity setDegrees:[NSNumber numberWithInt:degrees]];

        // Boolean
        BOOL isActive = [[trapObject objectForKey:ISACTIVE] integerValue] == 1 ? YES : NO;
        [trapEntity setIsActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isActive]];

        // Float
        float lat = [[trapObject objectForKey:LAT] floatValue];
        float lon = [[trapObject objectForKey:LON] floatValue];
        [trapEntity setLat:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:lat]];
        [trapEntity setLon:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:lon]];

        // NSString
        [trapEntity setDirection:[trapObject objectForKey:DIRECTION]];
        [trapEntity setTrapDescription:[trapObject objectForKey:DESCRIPTION]];
        [trapEntity setPoly0:[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGON_A]];
        [trapEntity setPoly1:[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGON_B]];
        [trapEntity setPoly2:[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGON_C]];
        [trapEntity setPolygonAzimut1:[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGON_A_AZIMUTH]];
        [trapEntity setPolygonAzimut2:[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGON_B_AZIMUTH]];
        [trapEntity setPolygonAzimut3:[trapObject objectForKey:POLYGON_C_AZIMUTH]];
        // etc. for all properties ...

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"HANDLE ERROR WHEN SAVING THE OBJECT");
            success = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I will glad to know how can I update correctly as I'm also missing this feature right now.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to martin, the code works like a charm.

Comment: You said "Right now, the function add the first object, then over and over again go to 'update'" Where is your update function?

Comment: The update should be in 'if (success)', I didn't build yet because I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but your checking for an error 
condition or for an empty result is wrong. It should be

```
BOOL success = true;
Trap *trap = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    NSLog(@"HANDLE ERROR");
    success = false;
} else if ([results count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"NOTHING TO UPDATE | ADD NEW");
    trap = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trap" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
} else {
    NSLog(@"UPDATE EXISTING OBJECT");
    trap = result[0]; // There should be only one object for the ID.
}
if (trap != nil) {
    // Set properties for new or existing object ...
    [trap setTrapID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trap_id]];
    // etc. for all properties ...

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"HANDLE ERROR WHEN SAVING THE OBJECT");
        success = false;
    }
}
```

`executeFetchRequest` returns

- `nil` if an error occurred, and
- an empty array if no matching objects were found.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Can you help me How can I update/modify?

Comment: 'trapObject' is differet each and every time.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I edited the code with your answer. First time I get 'NOTHING TO UPDATE | ADD NEW', rest of the times I get 'UPDATE EXISTING OBJECT', then the UI got stuck, and I see in the DB only one record.

Comment: @IdanMoshe: Sorry, but I have no idea why your UI gets stuck :-) Note that you should remove the old `trapEntity = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];` line from your code.

Comment: I removed the line, results are the same. Still one object in DB.

Comment: @IdanMoshe: So you call your method with dictionaries having *different* IDs, but only one Trap object is created ever?

Comment: Strange. Perhaps single-step in the debugger and check what happens. Suggestions: Verify that `int trap_id = ...` is assigned the correct value. (Is `ID` identical to `@"trapID"` ?). NSLog the predicate and the fetch request. NSLog the newly created Trap object and check if the ID is set correctly.

Comment: OK, it was my bad, 'NSInteger trapID = [trapObject[@"trapID"] integerValue];' should be 'NSInteger trapID = [trapObject[@"id"] integerValue];'. Now it works great, thanks a lot for your help!